# Como acessar o Tomcat que está dentro de uma máquina Vagrant?

Tags: tomcat, vagrant, centos

Estou começando a aprender sobre o Vagrant. 
Comecei aprovisionando uma máquina com Centos 7 Minimal, instalei o Java e o Tomcat, rodei o Tomcat, verifiquei nos processos que ele está rodando, mas não consigo acessar ele através da minha máquina.

Configurei um ip estático para esta máquina de diversas formas, mas a última configuração foi a seguinte:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define :tomcat do |tom|
      tom.vm.box = "relativkreativ/centos-7-minimal"
      tom.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  end

end
```

Eu dou um ping a partir da minha máquina no ip que configurei (192.168.33.10) e está tudo certo, inclusive quando desligo minha vm do Vagrant o ping para de funcionar como deveria ser.

Aparentemente tudo certo mas não consigo acessar a URL através da minha máquina: http://192.168.33.10:8080 informando que a página não está disponível. Porém quando verifico na vm a porta 8080 está sendo utilizada pelo java também como deveria ser.

Se servir como informações extras:

- Minha máquina é um Mac
- Sim, todas as configurações no Vagrant que fiz restartei a vm
- Tanto o java quanto o tomcat instalei via yum

Alguém sabe o que poderia ser? Como faço para acessar o tomcat a partir da minha máquina? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei diversas sugestões de solução que se baseavam em mexer nas configurações do Tomcat, mas no fim das contas acabei encontrando a solução correta que se tratava do firewall do Centos.

A solução é ativar a porta 8080 no firewall com os seguintes comandos:

```
    firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent 
    firewall-cmd --reload
```

Essa solução foi encontrada no serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/677743/not-able-to-access-tomcat-webserver-from-another-machine-in-the-lan?newreg=016ef66355174df3aa4ccf537d5cc536